# Which browsers don't support for ASP.NET based website?

Tags: asp.net, browser

I would like to have a list of browsers which don't support a website created based on .net.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ASP.NET web sites emit HTML, CSS and javascript (just like other technologies), and as such should be readable by ALL browsers. The technology used to host the site should have little impact on its consumption by browser clients.

The ony real concern is when non-conforming HTML or CSS is present and the web site doesn't render properly.

Answer (score 1):

All of them support ASP.Net. More often you will need to look at the **[browser market share](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=1)** and all browsers mentioned in the report support ASP.Net very so you can be rest assured that your asp.net site will be usable for almost everybody on earth.

[alt text http://marketshare.hitslink.com/chartfx62/temp/CFT0220_014339215AE.png](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=1)

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET is server side, so your answer is any and every web browser.